# bootstrap-editable: datepicker is not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

When I click in the table in column link, I open the dialog of bootstrap-editable. My call is:

```
$('TABLE TD A').editable({
     type: 'date',
     name: 'test',
     pk: $(this).attr("pk"),
     format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
     url: '/post',
     title: 'Cambiar 
});
```

the table is inside DIV.

what it is wrong it is the table with class table-condensed inside DIV.datepicker-days.

The table expands to all POPOVER instead to do it to all expand to DIV.datepicker-days.

I have as CSS:

```
<link href="../../Contents/Styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Contents/Styles/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
<link href="../../Contents/Styles/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

In this order.

The correct way to see it is : [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/63/)

What is it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes cambiar was an error but it isnt the answer

in js I should change the template and  in the table I set layout:fixed and I set the width

```
'<table class="table-condensed" style="width: 80px; padding-right: 15px !Important;table-layout: fixed;">'
```

Now it is working

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing a quote on the end of

'Cambiar'

```
$('TABLE TD A').editable({
     type: 'date',
     name: 'test',
     pk: $(this).attr("pk"),
     format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
     url: '/post',
     title: 'Cambiar' 
});

//ajax emulation
$.mockjax({
    url: '/post',
    responseTime: 200
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/snlacks/dxavLrbh/2/