# datepicker: I am trying to start in monday the calendar of bootstrap-editable using weekStart

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set Monday as start week using editable:

```
 $('TABLE TD A').editable({
    type: 'date',
    name: 'test',
    language: "es-ES",
    pk: $(this).attr("pk"),
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    url: '/post',
    title: 'Cambiar Fecha',
    weekStart: 1
});
```

It is not working. I am using bootstrap 3

It starts on Sunday anyway do I have to force it by js maybe?

Comment: Use datetimepicker to get calender functions

Comment: Use lower case in the tag names in your selector.

Comment: possible duplicate of [bootstrap-editable: datepicker is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629014/bootstrap-editable-datepicker-is-not-working)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker 3.0.0 - week starts at Monday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410685/bootstrap-3-datetimepicker-3-0-0-week-starts-at-monday)